# Run streamlit locally without installing

Tags: python, streamlit, auto-py-to-exe

How can I run `streamlit` file without installing it?

I have tried turning it into an exe and it told me that it wasn't a recognized command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi  hope you are doing fine!

I am not very sure if it will work in your case, but from my point of view, the easiest solution will be to make a Docker image from your "app" and then just run it as a Docker container instead of making a binary or exe file. The main benefit is that you will be able to easily run it on any machine and OS not only on Windows, plus the whole environment will be isolated too.

There is an example of how to do it: https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/deploy/docker